# Extracting data using Mechanize gem. Parsing data with CSS header

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web-scraping, mechanize, data-extraction

I am trying to extract data from a website (http://oregonpinotnoirwine.com/) using Mechanize.

I am able to go to the website and select search field. But I am not able to get the data. I am doing this on Ruby IRB.

```
require 'mechanize'
agent = Mechanize.new

agent.get("http://oregonpinotnoirwine.com/search.php")
form = agent.page.forms[0]
form["wineava"] = "Dundee Hills"
form.submit
```

Then I am trying to extract all the list of wines that are on the website. So in order to do that, I looked up CSS of the website and decided to use .a like

```
 agent.page.search(".a")
```

But that didn't return anything. But when I type

```
agent.page.search(".")
```

It returns all the data from the website. Now I'm just trying different variations.. when I type

```
agent.page.search("#wineava")
```

It returns with the dropdown option from the site but not the wine list..

Comment: `.a` selects all elements where class contains 'a'. You probable want `a` which selects all 'a' elements (links)

Answer (score 0):

So I was over-thinking with this.

All the data I needed was on the dropdown menu. So after accessing the website through

```
agent.get("http://oregonpinotnoirwine.com/search.php")
```

I was able to get the data I need by

```
agent.page.search("#winemaker")
```

But this method will not work if the items were not displayed in the dropdown menu.. Would it?

Comment: `agent.page.search("#winemaker")` is returning the HTML tag that is `id="winemaker"` in it's attributes. Most of the time there will be some identifying element to help you target what you need. For example, there will usually be a class, name, id, or something in a parent container to help you target them. Worst case scenario is that you find a specific tag matching a known name and then jump to the appropriate parent container.